# My android app skips part of code

Tags: android, string, navigation-drawer

as in topic my app skips code. Do not ask why do I use thread, it also happens with try/catch. After few hours testing i found it is related to that i have android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout in .xml. Does anyone know the solution for this?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private String[] drawerListViewItems = new String[]{"Test","Also test","Guess what","Another test"};
private ListView drawerListView;
String a="one";
int i=0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // get list items from strings.xml
  //  drawerListViewItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.items);
    TextView lol = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView1);
    lol.setText("#YOLO");
    new Thread (new Runnable() {  // This whole thread is skipped for no reason.
        public void run() {
                a="SWAG";
                i++;
            }            
    }).start();
    lol.setText(a+" "+i);
    // get ListView defined in activity_main.xml
    drawerListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

            // Set the adapter for the list view
    drawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.drawer_listview_item, drawerListViewItems));

}
```

}

Of course output is "one 0" in my app. I want it to be "SWAG 1" and i need it to be in thread. Also, do not ask why i use strings like that :) Oh, and there is .xml file:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- The main content view -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <TextView android:text="TextView"
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

```
<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="#666"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:background="#333"
    android:paddingLeft="15sp"
    android:paddingRight="15sp"
    />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is not skipped. You are making the wrong assumption the ui thread is waiting your thread to finish its execution. The quick fix is to have a method the update the TextView

```
private void updateTextView() {
  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          TextView lol = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView1);
          lol.setText(a+" "+i);
        }
   });
}
```

and call this method in your thread, after you updated the data. Note also that `setText` has to run on the UI Thread

Answer (score 0):

The thread is not skipped.  You are assuming that your entire program runs synchronously, which it does not.  The way you have it written, the UI thread has no way of properly communicating with the thread that you create.

When your code hits `new Thread(...)` part, it will spawn a new thread and run in concurrently to the UI thread.  So the value of `a` may or may not be what you expect depending on whether your back ground thread finishes before `setText()` or after.

There are multiple ways of communicate back with the UI thread.

Use [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) and send message back to the UI thread from your background thread.

Use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and set the updated value in `onPostExecute`

Use [runOnUIThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)) as suggested in the other answer.

Or in your case just don't spawn another thread.

[Here](http://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/index.html) some more info on multithreading in android.